# Why $PATH inside knitr code chunk is different from $PATH in Terminal?

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown, knitr

The $PATH echoed inside knitr BASH chunk has missing some of the paths from the $PATH in my MACOS Terminal.
Why is that? is there any way to set the default $PATH in bash engine in knitr the same as in Terminal?

1- in knitr:

````
```{bash}
echo $PATH
```
````

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/local/

2- in Terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/xxx/miniconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Applications/vcflib/bin:/Applications/bedtools

Answer (score 3):

That's because when you launch a shell through a GUI in OSX/MacOS `.profile` (and `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`) aren't run. The difference is essentially that of a [*login shell* and a *non-login shell*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)

In Terminal, run `cat ~/.profile` to see what your `.profile` contains. It will vary from user to user and you are free to modify it to your own preferences.

There are various ways to make `$PATH` in R match the `.profile` one. Most immediate is to add paths using `Sys.setenv(PATH=...)`, but this only works per session, it will be reset when you restart R. A more permanent option is to put the `Sys.setenv(PATH=...)` in `.Rprofile`, or define `PATH` in `.Renviron`.