# How to set $PATH variable in Spyder console equal to $PATH in terminal?

Tags: terminal, path, spyder

I am working on macos and I encountered some troubles with Spyder. I will try to be as clear as I can.

---

### Issue

I found out that my $PATH variable in my iterm2 terminal is not the same as the one in the iPython console from Spyder.

`echo $PATH` in terminal gives me:

```
...
/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:
...
/Library/TeX/texbin:
/opt/X11/bin:
```

However in Spyder:

```
import os
os.system("echo $PATH")
```

gives me:

```
...
/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:
...
/opt/X11/bin:
```

The path to **basictex** is not present.

---

### What I tried

For now the only fix I found is to add

```
export PATH="/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH"
```

in

```
/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/pythonw
```

Which is surely not the cleanest way to solve my issue...

I already checked

- [Why $PATH inside knitr code chunk is different from $PATH in Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986881/why-path-inside-knitr-code-chunk-is-different-from-path-in-terminal)
- [PATH variable not updating in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68865093/path-variable-not-updating-in-spyder)

But it didn't help me to answer to my question

---

### What I am looking for

**I am looking for a "clean" way to make the $PATH variable in the Spyder terminal be equal to the paths in `.zshrc` and in `/etc/paths.d`**.

I guess the $PATH variable for the Spyder terminal is set in `~/.spyder-py3/`.

There is a file `~/.spyder-py3/config/defaults/defaults-spyder-63.0.0.ini` where:

```
preload_modules = numpy, scipy, ..., os.path
```

and `~/.spyder-py3/lsp_paths` which may be what I am looking for ?

Could you help me ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Are you using the IPython Console, the Spyder terminal plugin, or maybe both? You could use the `PYTHONPATH` to add the missing path to your `PATH` while using Spyder. For that, inside Spyder, you can add paths to the `PYTHONPATH` by going to `Tools > PYTHONPATH manager`. There you can add paths, put them as enable/disable, etc.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your answer. I am using the the IPython Console. Indeed it works but each time I will install something new with a new PATH I will have to add it manually to the `PYTHONPATH`. Do you know if there is a way to automate this task ?

Comment: You can also modify the variables being added for Spyder to the `PYTHONPATH` by changing the `path` file (at `~/.spyder-py3`) directly (one line per path).

Comment: I have 2 folders: `~/.spyder-py3/lsp_paths/root_path` and `~/.spyder-py3/lsp_paths/cwd`. In which one should I add my paths ?

Comment: You don't have a file at `~/.spyder-py3/path` ? If not you should create it and add there the paths you want to add (one line per path)

Comment: Okay I created the file `~/.spyder-py3/path` and added the missing path. It works, thank you very much !

Comment: Awesome! Glad is working